# Why does my reduce based average function return NaN?

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, prototype

Trying to get the average of an array.

```
Array.prototype.average = function() {
    var sum = 0;
    this.reduce(function(a, b) {
        sum = a + b;
    });
    return sum / this.length;
};

[2, 15, 7].average();
```

Why does the `average` function call return `NaN`?

Comment: From your code, one would assume you are targeting a modern browser. I would suggest using `Object.defineProperty` to extend the `Array.prototype`. (and testing that the method doesn't exist first). You could even make the code more generic to work `(call/apply)`  with other objects.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your program didn't work because, `a` has the accumulated value from the previous function call. The first time, first two values of the array will be used. So `sum` will become `17` (`2 + 15`). Since you are not returning anything from the function, `undefined` will be returned, by default, and that will be used as the value for `a`, in the next call. So, the evaluation goes like this

```
a: 2,          b: 15   => 17
a: undefined,  b: 7    => NaN
```

So, `sum` will have `NaN`, since `undefined + 7` makes it so. Any numeric operation on `NaN`, will always give `NaN`, that is why `NaN / this.length`, gives you `NaN`. You can fix your program, just by returning the current value of `sum` whenever the function is called, so that on the next function call, `a` will have proper accumulated value.

```
Array.prototype.average = function() {
    var sum = 0;
    this.reduce(function(a, b) {
        sum = a + b;
        return sum;
    });
    return sum / this.length;
};
```

But we are not making use of the power and flexibility of `reduce` here. Here are two important points to consider when using `reduce`.

1. [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) accepts a second parameter which says the initial value to be used. Whenever possible, specify that.
2. The first parameter in the function passed to `reduce` accumulates the result and that will be returned finally, make use of that. No need to use a separate variable to keep track of the results.

So your code would look better like this

```
Array.prototype.average = function() {

    var sum = this.reduce(function(result, currentValue) {
        return result + currentValue
    }, 0);

    return sum / this.length;

};

console.log([2, 15, 7].average());
# 8
```

`reduce` actually works like this. It iterates through the array and passes the current value as the second parameter to the function and the current accumulated result as the first parameter and the value returned from the function will be stored in the accumulated value. So, the sum is actually found like this

```
result: 0 , currentValue: 2   => 2    (Initializer value `0`)
result: 2 , currentValue: 15  => 17
result: 17, currentValue: 7   => 24
```

Since it ran out of values from the array, `24` will be returned as the result of the `reduce`, which will be stored in `sum`.

Answer (score 6):

Your anonymous addition function does not return any value, `reduce` works with functions that return a value:

Try:

```
Array.prototype.average = function() {
    var sum = this.reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }, 0);
    return sum/this.length;
};
```

Another possibility is that your array contains strings instead of numbers, thus you could want to coerce them to numbers with `return (+a) + (+b)`; as if you have `"10.0"` and `"20.0"`, adding them together gives `"10.020.0"`, which divided by any number again gives `NaN`.

Answer (score 2):

You already have the answer to your question provided by others, but I thought I'd just expand on my comment with an example.

```js
if (!Array.prototype.average) {
    Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'average', {
        value: function () {
            if (typeof this === 'undefined' || this === null) {
                throw new TypeError('Cannot convert argument to object');
            }

            var object = Object(this);

            return [].reduce.call(object, function (result, currentValue) {
                return +(currentValue) + result;
            }, 0) / object.length;
        }
    });
}

var out = document.getElementById('out');

out.textContent += [2, 15, 7].average() + '\n';
out.textContent += [].average.call({
    0: '2',
    1: '15',
    2: '7',
    length: 3
}) + '\n';
out.textContent += [].average.call('123') + '\n';
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Whatever value is returned from reduce, it becomes the first parameter in the next call, so you have to return something. Also if you're extending prototypes on purpose, make sure to check for existence first so you're not overriding someone else's method.

There is no need to create any other variables in the function body as it can all be implemented in one line.

```
if(!Array.prototype.average) {
  Array.prototype.average = function() {
    return this.reduce(function(a, b){ return a + b; }) / this.length;
  };
}
```

Also note that the second parameter of reduce isn't very useful when summing numbers, unless you're trying to sum up from a number other than zero, which isn't exactly summing a set of numbers.

There is more info on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce