# concatenate using Underscore reduce?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, concatenation

Could someone help me with this problem? I'm trying to 
use (Underscore) _.reduce to concatenate all strings in an array.

input:

```
['x','y','z']
```

output:

```
'xyz'
```

Here's how I started:

```
_.reduce(['x','y','z'], function(current, end) {
    return...
});
```

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful or not, but if you want to dig a little deeper into using fold (or reduce as Underscore calls it) check out this paper: http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~gmh/fold.pdf

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use [`Array.prototype.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) here. It would be more efficient than `reduce` for this case.

```
console.log(['x','y','z'].join(""));
// xyz
```

But if you want to use [`_.reduce`](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce), you can do it like this

```
_.reduce(['x', 'y', 'z'], function(accumulator, currentItem) {
    return accumulator + currentItem;
});
// xyz
```

`_.reduce` is just a wrapper over the native [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) in environments which support it. You can understand how `reduce` would handle the input, from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28392509/1903116), in detail.

Here is a short explanation.

Since there is no initial value passed to `_.reduce`, the first value in collection will be used as the accumulator value and the function is called with accumulator value and the second value. So, the function is called like this

```
accumulator : 'x'
currentItem : 'y'
-----------------
accumulator : 'xy' (because returned value will be passed again as accumulator)
```

and in the next call,

```
accumulator : 'xy'
currentItem : 'z'
-----------------
accumulator : 'xyz' (since no elements left, accumulator will be returned)
```

Comment: one question though... what do the function parameters mean exactly?  can they be any variables?

Comment: @RoryPerro I included a little more explanation. Please check that. Yes, the parameters can have any names (if that is what you are trying to ask)